# Fast way to compare a VARCHAR to another ones

Tags: postgresql, comparison, plpgsql, varchar

I have a processing in database that iterate over an entire table. At some point, I need to check if a `VARCHAR` matches any value in a column.

I want to know what is the fast way to do this. Do SQL comparison each time? Retrieve the table values to a `VARCHAR array`? Another solution?

The iteration in the table is over millions, so the comparison will be done million times. In the match table, there a few hundred values.

So, what is the best approach for this?

Comment: I would think this would be a standard join?  With the option of adding an index for better performance.

Comment: You need to check whether a VARCHAR matches any value in a table or any value in a *column*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an index on the `varchar` column in the small table. Then the look-up will be as fast as possible. A plain btree index (default) is good for the equality operator.

```
CREATE INDEX smalltbl_lookup ON smalltbl(lookup);
```

If you only look up some values, this will be the fastest way:

```
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM smalltbl WHERE lookup = bigtbl.lookup)
```

Resulting in an index search. If you look up all values (does not sound like you do), a `LEFT JOIN` is faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM bigtbl b
LEFT JOIN smalltbl s USING (lookup)
```

Transforming the values from the small table into array and checking there cannot compete with an index search.